# I need to know the steps to publish mvc Core on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

When i Published my Mvc Core I gut the errors from server
Common causes of this issue:

The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:

Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process’ stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

Answer (score -2):

http://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1779/how-to-publish-asp_net-core-web-application-via-visual-studio-2015.aspx

http://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1774/how-to-use-ftp-to-publish-application-via-visual-studio-2015.aspx?KBSearchID=239678

Please turn on allow .exe from your Control Panel --->Security--->Allow .Exe Files

Comment: it's not really clear what the question is, much less if this answer makes sense.  Also, this is a link only answer;  these answers very easily become useless if the links change.  If you believe the information in these links can shed light on the question and provide a good answer, then you should summarize the body of the links in the answer body, in more than one sentence.